# get data attribute of a clicked element in a linked function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a scenario like below how to get `imgt` in console:

```js
function test(e){
let tg = e.target.attr('data-tg');
console.log(tg); // error - target is undefined
}

$('button').on('click', function(e){
let fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
window[fn]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-tg='imgt' data-fn='test'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: By it's self, `e.target` is only an element and will not be able to have `.attr()` function. This should show in your Console. Suggest wrapping it, `$(e.target).attr()` to get proper result.

Comment: Also `window[fn]()` would be called with argument, shouldn't it? (`window[fn](e)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By it's self, `e.target` is only an element and will not be able to have `.attr()` function. This should show in your Console.

Also, you do not pass any arguments to the function. Consider the following.

```js
function test(e) {
  if (e == undefined) {
    console.log("Event is Undefined");
    return false;
  }
  let tg = $(e.target).data('tg');
  console.log(tg); // error - target is undefined
}

$("#btn-1").on('click', function(event) {
  let fn = $(this).data('fn');
  window[fn](event);
});
$("#btn-2").on('click', function(event) {
  let fn = $(this).data('fn');
  window[fn]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1" data-tg='imgt' data-fn='test'>Test 1</button><button id="btn-2" data-tg='imgt' data-fn='test'>Test 2</button>
```